# Como verificar se ao menos 1 checkbox foi selecionada?

Tags: php

```
            $carrosbr = $_POST['carrosbr'];
            $carrosin = $_POST['carrosin'];
            $corp = $_POST['corp'];
            $houses = $_POST['houses'];
            $vip = $_POST['vip'];
            $skins = $_POST['skins'];
            $guns = $_POST['guns'];
            $bases = $_POST['bases'];
            $eventos = $_POST['eventos'];
            $drift = $_POST['drift'];
            $rpg = $_POST['rpg'];
            $mtmt = $_POST['mtmt'];
            $dayz = $_POST['dayz'];
```

Eu tenho as variáveis acima, todas são de checkboxes.
E eu preciso verificar se pelo menos 1 delas está selecionada.

Ajuda ai!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com isso você verifica cada uma. E pode fazer o que desejar em seguida.

```
if(isset($_POST['carrosbr'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['carrosin'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['corp'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['houses'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['vip'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['skins'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['guns'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['bases'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['eventos'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['drift'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['rpg'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['mtmt'])) //faça algo
if(isset($_POST['dayz'])) //faça algo
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu consegui fazer por array. Coloquei tudo em um array, e depois usei a função in_array para verificar se existia o TRUE nas checkboxes. Mesmo assim, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Usando array, você poderia até filtrar:

```
if(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)
```

em uma linha, você trataria todo o $_POST